# HAProxy log outgoing requests

Tags: logging, haproxy

Currently, my HAProxy logs have information about the incoming requests: HTTP version, method, host, path, and headers.

I am trying to debug my HAProxy config, and need to know what the resulting outgoing requests are, particularly the host and path.

How do I log outgoing requests so that I can debug HAProxy?

Answer (score 0):

"Outgoing" is relative, I believe, to whether you are proxying or reverse-proxying. I'd give you a detailed answer, but I think it's easier to point you to the specific CustomLog format of the documentation. http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#8.2.4

Comment: I am reverse proxying; I didn't know HAProxy could proxy. I see the log documentation, but I only see `http_request` which is the incoming request, not the (possibly modified) HTTP request HAProxy makes out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the log-format, in HA configs.

For example, I set in "default" section of haproxy.cfg as :-

```
log-format %ci:%cp-[%t]-%ft-%b/%s-[%Tw/%Tc/%Tt]-%B-%ts-%ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc-%sq/%bq
```

It gives me host, response time, ip etc... 
You can get log variables here :- 
http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/10/29/haproxy-log-customization/
like %H is for hostname.

Comment: Quote from HAProxy configuration manual: "This directive specifies the log format string that will be used for all logs resulting from traffic passing through the FRONTEND using this line." (Uppercasing by yours truly.) The question is about outgoing HTTP requestes, not incoming HTTP requests.